# Can anybody identify this alien looking font?

Tags: font-identification

I'm looking for this font. Here is a sample.  I have no ideas about it at all.

[image]

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is called 'ID4 Alien Script':

[image]

You can find it here:
http://font.downloadatoz.com/font,25814,id4-alien-script.html

Comment: Thanks!! You are a life saver.  Ok, maybe a week-saver but I still appriciate it!